# How To execute Robotium using ANT build

Tags: robotium, android-uiautomator

```
I am trying to run robotium using ANT build but it giving error : 

//The code to select the text using the robotium .

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

UiObject policy = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(
        "android.widget.TextView").textContains(t_o_s));
policy.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
solo.clickOnText("Privacy Policy");

-pre-compile:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 6 source files to C:\eclipse\NewClientAutomation\bin\clas
es
    [javac] C:\eclipse\NewClientAutomation\src\com\android\test\ca\AhaTest.java
18: error: package com.jayway.android.robotium.solo does not exist
    [javac] import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] C:\eclipse\NewClientAutomation\src\com\android\test\ca\AhaTest.java
40: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Solo solo ;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Solo
    [javac]   location: class AhaTest
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED


Please provide me the solution. how to include robotium class into the ANT.
```

How to configure the build path in ANT to include robotium .class file. 
I am using Uiautoamator screenshot function to take the screen and puttin robotium solo class to select the text in web view page. I want to use robotium class in the uiautomator using the ANT Build.

Comment: Please show you tests source. and ANT compile line.

Comment: UiObject policy = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(
    "android.widget.TextView").textContains(t_o_s));
  policy.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
  solo.clickOnText("Privacy Policy");            android create uitest-project -n L10ClientAutomation -t 2 -p "C:\Eclipse\NewClientAutomation"    ant build

Comment: Please add it to the your post

Comment: Looks like it can't find the Robotium libraries? You do have them under libs/ right?

Comment: that what my problem is i exactly do not know where to add roboitum library file in ANT. Please help me with . From which folder of robotium to which folder in ANT

Comment: @kanak You need not add it to ant file just have it under libs folder where your test code exists